# Have Hot Chip ever explained the lyric 'made in the dark' in the eponymous song?

Tags: lyrics

I discovered **Hot Chip**'s song [**"Made in the Dark"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKclGDgCAxc) a few months ago. It's exquisitely beautiful, and seems to describe the aftermath of the break up of a romantic relationship.

The chorus consists of the words: **'We were made in the dark.'** I find this both beautiful and intriguing. But what does it mean? Two plausible theories come to mind:

- When I first heard the song, it made me think, and indeed still does make me think, of **Psalm 139.15-16**, which reads in one translation: 'My frame was not hidden from you, when I was being *made in secret, intricately woven in the depths of the earth*. Your eyes saw my unformed substance; in your book were written, every one of them, the days that were formed for me, when as yet there was none of them.'
- Trawling through the speculations of fans online, the most common explanation I've come across is that **the relationship in question was based solely on physical intimacy**. The relationship began in the bedroom, and therefore was 'made in the dark' in the sense of being made in a private setting, or in a more literal sense.

Many are of the opinion that the meaning of a song is whatever the listener perceives it to be; I am not of that opinion. **Have Hot Chip themselves ever commented on the meaning behind this song?**

Comment: My interpretation is: "Our relationship is a product of darkness." Whether that refers to the darkness of the bedroom or some kind of metaphorical darkness, I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

Vocalist/keyboardist Alexis Taylor told the Sun newspaper that he thought this song contains the best lyrics he'd ever written.

Taylor explained the album title to Slate magazine: "I got to thinking about relationships and how quite an important moment takes place in the dark. As human beings, we are all 'made in the dark' to some extent. I was ruminating on the fact that important things you do are done by not speaking."

Ref: https://www.songfacts.com/facts/hot-chip/made-in-the-dark